# Modify link href with cloudflare workers

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to proxy subdomain.com to domain.com/blog with Discourse being the software for the blog.

I have the following code:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  var url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/blog/') || url.pathname === '/blog') {
    handleBlog(event, url);
  } else {
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
  }
})

async function handleBlog(event, url) {
  var originUrl = url.toString().replace(
    'https://example.com/blog',
   'https://subdomain.com');
  event.respondWith(fetch(originUrl)); 
}
```

It works, however the page don't work as all chrome gives a 404 error and I this is caused by those lines of code (examples):

```
<link rel="preload" href="/assets/browser-update-1741a2ed67a367faeb0a582af064457e8b1b1354e52e6efcf8bf26301166dec8.js" as="script">

<link href="/stylesheets/discourse-solved_2_d335db0449b9d3e518e949a991fe12b7c0af6ba3.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" data-target="discourse-solved" data-theme-id="3" />
```

I believe Chrome is trying to load the assets using the relatives paths so it uses the root domain, which doesn't have those assets to load, thus returning a 404 error.

How do I fix this issue, or if I'm wrong about the source of the issue, accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do would be using HTMLRewriter. See docs here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/html-rewriter/

Eg:

```js
class ElementHandler {
  element(element) {
    // An incoming element, such as `div`
    console.log(`Incoming element: ${element.tagName}`)
  }

  comments(comment) {
    // An incoming comment
  }

  text(text) {
    // An incoming piece of text
  }
}

async function handleRequest(req) {
  const res = await fetch(req)

  return new HTMLRewriter().on('div', new ElementHandler()).transform(res)
}
```

So in your case, you need a create new Rewriter instance and watch on event of `a` element. Call `setAttribute` of that element to modify its `href`.